# "Elimination" of terms in Simon's Algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I've started to study Quantum Information Technology and I stumbled upon a rather confusing statement while studying about Simon's Algorithm. I am pretty sure this isn't just something that is related to Quantum, but have no idea what to look for.

After looking into the state of the first register in the Simon's Algorithm solution, just after it leaves the second Hadamard, I have the state:
$$ | \psi\rangle  = \sum_{z}[(-1)^{x*z}+(-1)^{(x \oplus s)*z}]| z\rangle $$
After opening the brackets I get:
$$ | \psi \rangle = \sum_{z}[(-1)^{x*z}+(-1)^{x*z \oplus s*z}]| z\rangle $$

How do I extract the `(-1)^{x*z}` term? I guess this is a general question what happens when I have a bitwise mod 2 (or XOR) in the exponent?

The correct solution is:
$$ | \psi\rangle  = \sum_{z}[1+(-1)^{z*s}] |z\rangle $$

Comment: "\ket" is not a function/command in MathJax. You either have to define it as a new command, or use "| \psi \rangle".

Comment: Yea, that seems weird, when I wrote the post I saw the kets, then they disappeared for an unknown to me reason. Now I can see them again :D

Comment: Someone was nice enough to edit your post for you.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize thank you

Comment: You're welcome! But, it wasn't me, it was @mikestone (you can see the entire revision history of the post if you click on the "edited..." link in the bottom middle.

Comment: Seems more suited to [quantumcomputing.se]

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like the correct solution.

What you should get is the following:

First, notice that $s\cdot z$ can take two values, $0$ or $1$. Now consider one term in the sum, i.e.
$$
(-1)^{x\cdot z} + (-1)^{x\cdot z\,\oplus\,s\cdot z}\ .
$$
There are two cases:

1. For values of $z$ such that $s\cdot z=1$, the two terms $(-1)^{x\cdot z}$ and $(-1)^{x\cdot z\, \oplus\, s\cdot z}=(-1)(-1)^{x\cdot z}$ are opposite and thus cancel out.
2. For values of $z$ such that $s\cdot z=0$, the two terms are both equal $(-1)^{x\cdot z}$ -- this term therefore appears with a factor $2$.

You thus obtain
$$
\lvert\psi\rangle = 2 \sum_{z:\,s\cdot z =0} (-1)^{x\cdot z} \lvert z\rangle
$$
(where the sum runs over all $z$ with $s\cdot z = 0$).

A measurement of the state in the computational basis will then return a random $z$ with $s\cdot z=0$. If you know sufficiently many such $z$'s, you can use this to reconstruct $s$.